# Feasibility of introducing React to a locked-down SharePoint environment

Tags: reactjs

The job I work at has a locked-down SharePoint 2013 environment (no CDNs, no external pages, etc...)  Most work is done with SharePoint Designer or the SP UI, with Visual Studio and JavaScript as a last resort. Its worked so far for several years (since 2010-ish), so everybody senior to me is very comfortable with this setup.

Requests have gotten to a point where I'd like to use JavaScript libraries and files as opposed to just raw script tags in the view.  There's a lot of pushback for this, and I'd like to introduce it as simply as possible to avoid outright rejection.

My question is:  How feasible is it to use ReactJs and just drop the required files in '/SiteAssets' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard react workflow produces a bundle with all your dependencies already inside - no CDNs or external references of any kind. There's no reason you couldn't drop the bundle in SharePoint.  Your development machine will need to reach out to the internet to fetch those resources but SharePoint would not.